# Play framework 2. Rendering template inside ajax callback

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have template for rendering comments, `comment.scala.html`:

```
@(date: String, text: String, name: String)
...
<h4>@name</h4>  
<p>@date</p>  
<div>@comment</div>
```

Comments also adds to page with ajax, `sendcomment.js`:

```
$("#commentForm").submit(function () {
        jsRoutes.controllers.Posts.addComment($("#blogpostContainer").data("post-id")).ajax({
            success: function (data) {

              //here i populate data with js - my current solution
              var commentHtml = "<li><h4>" + data.name + ... +</li>"

              //but i want use comment template for populating data

                $("#commentsContainer").append(commentHtml);
                $('#commentForm').each(function () {
                    this.reset();
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!")
            },
            data: $("#commentForm").serialize()
        })
        return false;
    }
)
```

I know, that I can not mix Scala variables (server-side) with JS variables (client-side).
My question - how I can use html template for rendering ajax callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @Ryan's answer, the only way to reuse comment.scala.html in its Scala form is to return HTML instead of JSON.

**Pros**

- Code re-use
- Type safety

**Cons**

- Possibly increased bandwidth usage, if the size of the HTML > size of the JSON)

To do this, your controller method is going to look something like this pseudo-code, not including error checking and so on.  I'm assuming Java, but the logic of the Scala version is the same.

```
public static F.Promise<Result> addComment() {
    return F.Promise.promise(() -> convert POST data to a comment object)
                    .map(comment -> comment.save())
                    .map(comment -> ok(comment.render(comment.date, 
                                                      comment.text,
                                                      comment.userName)));
}
```

Your JavaScript would then look something like

```
$("#commentForm").submit(function () {
  jsRoutes.controllers.Posts.addComment($("#blogpostContainer").data("post-id")).ajax({
    success: function (data) {
      $("#commentsContainer").append(commentHtml);
      $('#commentForm').each(function () {
        this.reset();
      });
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("Error!")
    },
    data: $("#commentForm").serialize()
  })
  return false;
})
```

Comment: There's an interesting discussion of this approach [here](http://blog.knoldus.com/2015/04/17/play-framework-has-lost-its-relevance-or-has-it/).

Answer (score 1):

Just like variables, Scala templates are also rendered server side.

You can:

1. Render HTML server side and return that in the AJAX call
2. Use a client side template library (there are many)